# QProcess::execute Environment Variables Expanded Strings

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

How do I get this to work:

`QProcess::execute("%windir%\system32\SnippingTool.exe")`

I assume expanded environment variables strings are being ignored by QProcess.

I guess I'll need to parse the string and see if `%` exists and then get the environment variable to complete the full string path. Sounds like hassle and something that should be handled by `QProcess`. Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You might want to have a look at [`QProcessEnvironment`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocessenvironment.html).

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried using `QProcessEnvironment` and it doesn't solve my problem, i.e when the system using custom environment variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you want to use `%windir%` directly, you can do something like this:

```cpp
QProcess::execute("cmd.exe /c start /WAIT "" %windir%\\system32\\SnippingTool.exe");
```

- Else, you can use for example `qgetenv("windir")` or `qEnvironmentVariable("windir")` to get the windows folder path.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Creative! Thanks Tom! :)

Comment: sorry for jumping with another question, but do you know why it would'nt work when command contain spaces? `QString szCommand = "cmd /c start \"\" \"" + QString::fromStdString(szProc) + "\"";`
Looks like if I start the exact same command from the command prompt it works, so I guess this has to do something with QProcess.

Comment: The only work around I found for this(but ugly), is taking the command string, writing to disk as `.bat/.cmd` script file and with QProcess executing it and then deleting the file. That works, but relative weird way of doing things. :/

Comment: Try this: `QString szCommand = "cmd /c \"start \"\" \"+ QString::fromStdString(szProc) +\"\"";`

Comment: The `/Wait` parameter is important here. If you want to `QProcess::execute` to do his job, which is: to launch and wait for the end of a program/command, you need to add `/Wait`.

Comment: Thanks Tom, but I already tried this one and it didn't work. it shows in my debugger that it slices the string where spaces are. Regarding the `/wait` parameter, in my case I don't need it, because it's a background service that that launches another program. So it's like, run and go :)

Comment: You're welcome, I made a small mistake in the code, it should be like this: 
`QString szCommand = "cmd /c \"start \"\" \""+ QString::fromStdString(szProc) +"\"\"";`

Comment: Just gave this another shot, still slices the string where space. :(

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @**TomKim** answer for handling expanded strings in his answer, I got that problem solved. ***But*** unfortunately white spaces caused other issues for me that made me come up with this solution that hopefully will help others. Not the prettiest solution though, but it does exactly I needed for multiple platforms:

```
void QuickCut::executeProcess(const std::string & szProc, const std::string & szArgs)
{
    // QProc won't expand environment variable strings.
    // Invoking using the user console will allow for expanded string to work as expected.
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
    QString szCommand = "cmd /c start \"\" \"" + QString::fromStdString(szProc) + "\"";
    QString szExt = ".cmd";
#elif Q_OS_UNIX
    QString szCommand = "sh -c '" + QString::fromStdString(szProc) + "'";
    QString szExt = ".sh";
#endif

    QStringList qArgsTmp = QString::fromStdString(szArgs).trimmed().split(",");
    for (auto && arg : qArgsTmp)
    {
        QString argTrimmed = arg.trimmed();
        if (argTrimmed.isEmpty()) continue;

        szCommand += " " + argTrimmed;
    }
    qDebug() << "[QuickCut::executeProcess] - Execute Command: " << szCommand;

    QString szFilePath = applicationDirPath() + "/tempCmd" + szExt;
    QFile file(szFilePath);
    file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    QTextStream ts(&file);
    ts << szCommand;
    file.close();
    QProcess::execute(szFilePath);
    file.remove();
}
```

Comment: maybe by security, you should use this to add your arguments : 
`szCommand += " \"" + argTrimmed + "\"";`. 
Prevention for arguments that contain spaces